# Show the derivability of a process using Itô's lemma

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

We have the process $Xt=log(\sqrt(Bt^2+Wt^2))$. Note that $Bt$ and $Wt$ are two independant standard browninan motions.
Now, we need to find an expression with the form: $dXt=...$ I`m pretty sure we will need Itô's lemma, but as a novice in stochastic process, I'm having a hard time to get started...

Comment: How is $X_0$ defined (assuming that both the BM's start at $0$)?

Comment: Yes both BM's start at 0. As for X0, it is only specified that t is part of [0,T].